# Компилятор не может найти шаблонную функцию ADL

Tags: c++

Почему компилятор не может найти функцию foo?

```
namespace X {

struct A {

};

template<typename T>
void foo(X::A) {

}

}

void bar(X::A x) {
    foo<int>(x);
}


int main() {
    bar(X::A{});
}
```

Comment: @Fqqlt Собственно тут весь вопрос в том, почему она не вызывается без `X::` (хотя нешаблонная функция вызвалась бы нормально)

Answer (score 1):

Потому что запись `foo<int>` представляет собой инстанцирование шаблона `foo` из текущего пространства имен. До ADL в этом случае даже не доходит.

> **17.9.1 Explicit template argument specification [temp.arg.explicit]**
> 8 [Note: For simple function names, argument dependent lookup (6.4.2) applies even when the function name is not visible within the scope of the call. This is because the call still has the syntactic form of a function call (6.4.1). But when a function template with explicit template arguments is used, the call does not have the correct syntactic form unless there is a function template with that name visible at the point of the call. If no such name is visible, the call is not syntactically well-formed and argument-dependent lookup does not apply. If some such name is visible, argument dependent lookup applies and additional function templates may be found in other namespaces. [Example:

namespace A {
    struct B { };
    template void f(B);
}
namespace C {
    template void f(T t);
}

void g(A::B b) {
f<3>(b); // ill-formed: not a function call
A::f<3>(b); // well-formed
C::f<3>(b); // ill-formed; argument dependent lookup applies only to unqualified names
using C::f;
f<3>(b); // well-formed because C::f is visible; then A::f is found by argument dependent lookup
}

—end example ] —end note ]